# Python: split one element in list

Tags: python, split

Can not solve problem i have following list ['882','200','60'] sometimes it can be ['882','200'] i want get list like this [['8','8','2'], '200', '60'].

Another words no matter how many items are in the list, we always split the first item

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get the first element:

```
l = ['882','200','60']
[e if i else list(e) for i,e in enumerate(l)]
```

output:

```
[['8', '8', '2'], '200', '60']
```

other examples

```
>>> [e if i else list(e) for i,e in enumerate(['123'])]
[['1', '2', '3']]

>>> [e if i else list(e) for i,e in enumerate(['882','200'])]
[['8', '8', '2'], '200']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['882','200','60']
mylist[0] = list(mylist[0])
```

Comment: nice one, simple and efficient ;) +1